# Vector size of predicted values ​increases automatically - logistic regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I tried to implement a logistic regression model from scratch. I discovered that the model executes just the first iteration. it seems that the predicted vector increase automatically. The shape of ypred changes from 1000 to 2000 on the second iteration.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem, please? thank you in advance! ,

```
     self.w=np.zeros((self.n,1))
     self.b=0
     #training loop
     for i in range (self.itr+1):
         #calculate hypotheses
         ypred = self.sigmoid(np.dot(X, self.w) + self.b)
         #cost 
         #ypred=ypred[:,0]
         ypred=ypred.flatten()
         print(ypred.shape)
         print(y.shape)
         cost= -(1/self.m)*np.sum(y*np.log(ypred)+ (1-y)*np.log(1-ypred))
         #gradient descent 
         dw=(1/self.m)*np.dot(X.T, (ypred-y))
         db=(1/self.m)*np.sum(ypred-y)
     
         self.w=self.w-self.lr*dw
         self.b=self.b-self.lr*db
```

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
x, y =make_blobs(n_samples=1000, centers=2)
lor=logiticREG(x)
w,b =lor.train(x,y)
ypred=lor.predict(x)
print(type(y))
print(ypred)
```

output :

```
(1000,)
(1000,)
iteration:   0 cost :    0.6931471805599454
(2000,)
(1000,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_33/2529728222.py in <module>
      2 x, y =make_blobs(n_samples=1000, centers=2)
      3 lor=logiticREG(x)
----> 4 w,b =lor.train(x,y)
      5 ypred=lor.predict(x)
      6 print(type(y))

/tmp/ipykernel_33/894464579.py in train(self, X, Y)
     21             print(ypred.shape)
     22             print(y.shape)
---> 23             cost= -(1/self.m)*np.sum(y*np.log(ypred)+ (1-y)*np.log(1-ypred))
     24             #gradient descent
     25             dw=(1/self.m)*np.dot(X.T, (ypred-y))

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1000,) (2000,)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To calculate the cost function, y and ŷ must be the same size! the feature array size is 1000, so I should have an array of 1000 elements as a result of training process, then  I compare this array with the real label (which is an array of 1000 elements). my problem is that this model gives me an array of 2000 elements.